# Dynamically created QWidget in QFormLayout does not have frame, even if explicitly asked to do so

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a little problem with this bit of code:

```
DatasetWidget::DatasetWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::DatasetWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // cut non-ui related stuff here ...

    // Add widgets
    for(int loop=0;loop<theAmountOfItemsWeAdd;++loop)
    {
        QLabel * ql=new QLabel("Caption");
        QLineEdit * qle=new QLineEdit(this);
        qle->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Policy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Policy::Fixed);
        ui->formDisp->addRow(ql,qle); // ui->formDisp is of type QFormLayout*
    }

// more non-UI related code
```

I'm creating a QLineEdit widget and adding it to a QFormLayout, "formDisp". For some weird reason that I can't figure out, the created QLineEdit does not have any frame and setFrame doesn't enable it.

I furthermore append the relevant parts of the .ui file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>DatasetWidget</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="DatasetWidget">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>723</width>
    <height>591</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Datensatz</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lblCaptionDatensatz">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Datensatz:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDatensatz">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
         <underline>true</underline>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>C-XXXX-XXX</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="leDescriptor">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="toolTip">
        <string extracomment="ServiceTag"/>
       </property>
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>7</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="cmdDelete">
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset resource="hawams.qrc">
         <normaloff>:/icons/res/trash-3x.png</normaloff>:/icons/res/trash-    3x.png</iconset>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formDisp"/>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="Line" name="line">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
<connections/>
</ui>
```

As widgets added in QtCreator look exactly how they are supposed to look, I suppose something about my code must be wrong.

**Update:** Problem solved: Surrounding QWidget was being used inside a QListView, where it replaced an older, fixed-size version of the widget. In the code that fills the QListView with items, there was a hard-coded size hint which forced Qt to resize the new (bigger) version of the QWidget and "squeeze" it vertically.
Conclusion: When you embed a QWidget derivate in buggy old code that resizes it so there isn't enough space anymore to display all items inside the QWidget's layout, things get messy.

Comment: Please show more of your code because these 4 lines is not enough

Comment: As I don't know which parts of the code are relevant, I appended some more context information.

Comment: Probably a silly question but... are you absolutely sure the QLineEdit doesn't have a frame?  On the system I'm sitting at the difference is barely perceptible.

Comment: Do you use stylesheets?

Comment: @G.M. I'm absolutely sure - the QLineEdit is on a white background (default background colour on my system for QWidgets that are inside a QListWidget, which is the case with the widget that we're talking about). It definitely doesn't have a frame.

Comment: @thuga, I do not use stylesheets. What I have tried is: 1. create a normal-looking default QLineEdit in qtcreator and 2. copy its style() using setStyle() into the dynamically created QLineEdit. Doesn't work either...

Comment: So if you add a line edit in the designer and run your application it looks fine? Can we see a screenshot of this?

Comment: @thuga - yes, exactly. Screenshot is appended to original post now. I changed the background colour of the widget to this dirty blue hue as a temporary fix to make the lineedits distinguishable from the background. The uppermost dynamically created widget does appear to have a frame, but it's not a QLineEdit - it's a QComboBox :-)

Comment: @KubaOber - I haven't looked into the uic generated code yet indeed. Will do, that's already a useful piece of advice.

Comment: **You are hurting yourself unnecessarily by not producing a minimal test case that actually reproduces the problem**. This question cannot be answered unless you take something like my answer and tweak it until it doesn't work anymore, then show it as a unit that can be compiled and ran to demonstrate. Otherwise, we'll be running in circles and this question is of very low quality because of that!

Answer (score 0):

The `setFrame(true)` is a no-op since the frame is set by default.

Alas, I can't reproduce - the following has both line edits looking identical, save for their size, and their minimum sizes are set to different values, with the second one being larger than first one. A `QFormLayout` does not enforce a fixed row height!

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/lineedit-frame-37831979
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtUiTools>

const char ui[] = R"EOF(
  <ui version="4.0">
   <class>DatasetWidget</class>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="DatasetWidget">
    <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lblCaptionDatensatz">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Datensatz:</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lblDatensatz">
       <property name="text">
        <string>C-XXXX-XXX</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="leDescriptor">
       <property name="maxLength">
        <number>7</number>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <layout class="QFormLayout" name="formDisp"></layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  <connections/>
  </ui>)EOF";

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QBuffer buf;
   buf.setData(ui, sizeof(ui));
   auto w = QUiLoader().load(&buf);
   auto & layout = *w->findChild<QFormLayout*>("formDisp");
   QLineEdit edit1, edit2;
   layout.addRow("Edit1", &edit1);
   layout.addRow("Edit2", &edit2);
   edit1.setMinimumHeight(50);
   edit2.setMinimumHeight(100);
   w->show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hello,
thanks for the reply. Yes, setFrame(true) is a no-op, but as the screenshot shows, the QLineEdits that are generated by my code do not have frames. What I expect are QLineEdits with a visible frame, like the QLineEdit at the top of the screenshot that says "123ABCD" and was *not* generated by my own code. Maybe this clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. First Widget added to QFormLayout is a QLabel. The row height is then set to the height of the label. All following widgets get stuffed into the "too narrow" rows and if Qt attempted to draw a frame around them, the text line wouldn't fit into them anymore - so there is no frame. Solution: e.g. `setMinimumHeight(32)` on the first element that is being added to the QFormLayout.

There was also a second mistake. The whole QWidget is the graphical representation of a dataset, and in the main application many instances of this widget are used in a QListView to display the result of a database query. Before the use of the dynamically created QWidget, I had used a static widget with a fixed size. This size was used as sizeHint inside the code that filled the QListView, and I totally forgot about that. After removing the wrong sizeHint in the code of the application's main window, also the `setMinimumHeight(someInt)` wasn't needed anymore.

Comment: There's no fixed row height in a form layout. It adapts to the requirements of each of the widgets. You're still doing something else wrong. See the edit on my answer. What is the exact platform and style you're using? Perhaps you're using a broken style that doesn't give proper sizeHints or minimum sizes for widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the commitment. Yes, it turned out something else was wrong as well. I'm on a Linux desktop and I'm using the default style that Qt applications use when you create a new Qt project from scratch in QtCreator, I think in Linux that's the Plastique style but I'm not sure.
However, there is indeed a second mistake that I made which I will append to my answer in a minute.

Comment: Your question is completely inadequate, then. Please either amend it to cleanly demonstrate the problem you're having, or delete it. By not starting from a minimum test case like I did, you wasted a lot of time. I guess that 50%+ of SO questions would be unnecessary if only their askers bothered to follow the requirements that their questions should have adhered to and are spelled out in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). More than 10% of my answers simply highlight the inadequacy of the questions with "works for me". That's not good.

Comment: @KubaOber I'm sorry, it's my first ever question on SO. It wasn't easy to develop a minimum test case in which the same problem would appear - the fact that there is a link between the actual size of a widget and whether it draws a frame or not was unknown to me and I think also tweaking with a fully working test case wouldn't have pointed me to it. But I thank you for your commitment, looking at the uic generated code poked me into the right direction.

Comment: "It wasn't easy to develop a minimum test case in which the same problem would appear" That's the whole point: as long as you can't, you shouldn't ask, because you don't know what problem you're asking for help with! And by the time you understand the source of the problem, you might have the solution at hand too. Only if you don't, you ask. That has nothing to do with asking on SO, that's how you efficiently solve problems. If you don't have a test case, you yourself don't even know what the question **is**! It then reads as "hey, there's this going on, dunno anything about it, help".

Comment: Ok, understood. On the plus side, *if* somebody has the same problem as I initially had (even an explicit setFrame(true) has no visible effect), if they google it now they will find one possible fix to their problem. And I disagree, I knew what the question was - "why can't I see a frame around the widgets", answer: "because they are too small, size matters". It wasn't the root of my problem, I admit, but a lot of "hey, there's this going on"-posts on SO that are of this kind have actually pushed me in the right direction already.